# what is the "77u/" in front of base64 encoded strings?

Tags: base64

I'm accessing a data entry in a CSV file I requested from a server.

The value in the data entry is 77u/REFUQV9EUwo=  and decodes to "DATA_DS"(without quotes). Theres also another issue as if I write the decoded message to a file I end up getting:
"DATA_DS
"
(with quotes)
What is the point of the 77u/ if when removing it I still get DATA_DS on the online base64 decoders and is it the reason that the formatting is getting screwed up?

Answer (score 6):

"77u/" is `0xef 0xbb 0xbf` in base64 encoding. Those three bytes are the UTF-8 encoding of the byte order mark, which is used to signal endianness and encoding of unicode text.

Answer (score 0):

This is maby better known under BOM. Eg. UTF-8 BOM Encoding